# geoNear pulling inacurate results in MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb, aggregation-framework, geo

In my DB there are comments, each comment has each country Long Lat, but MongoDB giving a result that is inaccurate, i.e I'm providing Brazil [Lon Lat] as Input in query

```
 db.posts.aggregate([ { "$geoNear": {

         "near": [-69.7145414,-13.6574511 ],
         "spherical": true,
         "distanceField": "distance",
         "num":1000000,
        "query":{"post_id":"5efc430e25a363375860e842",}
     }},
     {
        "$sort":{"distance":1}
     } ])
```

What I'm getting a result is

1. Bolivia (409.5 km far from Brazil)
2. Paraguay (1293 km far from Brazil)
3. Peru (1645 km far from Brazil)
4. Guyana (1188 km far from Brazil)

> you can see that

- Result 4 is near rather than result 2, so it should be at position 2
  This is how I'm getting inaccurate result.

> Distance calculated using this website:
> https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

*Longitude Latitude That I'm using are as follows*

```
"Bolivia" => [
    "latitude" => -16.0705819,
    "longitude" => -72.5931926
],
"Paraguay" => [
    "latitude" => -23.3601858,
    "longitude" => -62.9462413
],
"Peru" => [
    "latitude" => -9.1084506,
    "longitude" => -84.0750546
],
"Guyana" => [
    "latitude" => 4.9392707,
    "longitude" => -63.4541328
],
"Brazil" => [
    "latitude" => -13.6574511,
    "longitude" => -69.7145414
]
```

> These Latitude/Longitude get using with this link: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Brazil/@-13.6574511,-69.7145414,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x9c59c7ebcc28cf:0x295a1506f2293e63!8m2!3d-14.235004!4d-51.92528

Comment: Do you consider [-69.7145414,-13.6574511] as Brazil? This is Peru.

Comment: `num` is not a valid option, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: Add the input data to your question that shows the distances you are querying with (and ideally is runnable by others).

Comment: @Werfried it is long lat of brazil... you can verify it from here https://www.google.com/maps/place/Brazil/@-13.6574511,-69.7145414,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x9c59c7ebcc28cf:0x295a1506f2293e63!8m2!3d-14.235004!4d-51.92528

Comment: @D.SM forget about num.. suppose num is not there.. still results are inaccurate

Comment: @D.SM I can send you complete array of lat long , for each country , you can insert it into your db and can fetch it, for this you've to open chat so that I can share it there

Comment: Add the reproduce code to the question. You need one document inserted and one query, right?

Comment: 1- I inserted all lat long(one lat long for one document) since there are 195 countries in my array so I inserted 195 documents
2- Execute given query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217062/discussion-between-ali-bhutta-and-d-sm).

Comment: Pick one country that produces incorrect result and test with that country only.

Comment: In example I mentioned brazil.. that is producing wrong results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got why I'm getting inaccurate distance/results, Although it is not a solution to my problem, however now I know about the reason If someone knows best reason or solution then I'm in wait, Thank you

> MongoDB assumes earth is perfect sphere and uses average radius of
> earth to calculate distance between two points. But as you know earth
> is not sphere but more sort of Ellipsoid so distance calculation will
> not be perfect but approximate in MongoDB. However, Google uses a very
> complex formula to get better results. They do have huge database of
> radius of the earth at different locations on earth.